# mysql to CSV with column names on first row inserted dynamically

Tags: mysql, csv, field-names

I'm revising my original question significantly...

This works perfectly for dumping your table to a CSV with the field names on the first row.

```
SELECT 'field1', 'field2', 'field3' 
UNION SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/var/tmp/table_name.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM table_name;
```

However, when you have hundreds of fields and new fields are added or fields are changed or deleted from time to time I need something dynamic that will put the field names in the format above dynamically so this query will work in a script anytime without having to manually update the field names by hand.

Answer (score 11):

How about -

```
SELECT CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ','), "\n")
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tbl'
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```

You could pass the output from this to a new_file and then append the data from the the outfile query -

```
cat /var/tmp/table_name.csv >> new_file
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have revised my question to be more specific though.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do it with UNION but you can use the above to add the file created by your `SELECT * INTO OUTFILE...` to the ouput from the information schema query.

Comment: Around here we say thanks by accepting answers. Just click on the tick to the left of the answer you want to accept.